# Automator "copy finder object" with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator

I have created an Apple Automator service that

- receives PDFs
- encrypts them
- copies the encrypted PDF to a destination folder
- renames the encrypted PDF

These are all commands from the Automator. However, the copying as an Automator command can only copy to a pre-defined folder.

I would like to control this part by an AppleScript which reads out the user name and selects a folder accordingly:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set user_script to "echo $USER"
    set username to do shell script user_script
    
    if username = "A" then
        set standardpfad to "/Users/" & username & "/whatever"
    else if username = "B" then
        set standardpfad to "/Users/" & username & "/foo"
    else
        display dialog "I don't know this user!" with title "ERROR" buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
        return
    end if
    
    #actual copying
                
end run
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to handle the input in way that it resembles the "Copy Finder object" command in Automator. Can anyone please help me?

Thank you!

Edit:
Automator screenshot
[image: Automator screenshot]

Comment: You can use Automator variables to set the destination at run-time; have you looked at that? It would also help to know more about your program flow. Does this workflow process files in bulk; use a Loop action to process them one by one; or is it only meant to work on files one at a time?

Comment: The workflow receives highlighted files from finder and is executed via shortcut or context menu. I noticed the possibility of defining variables but have not seen any possibility of doing this based on username. That's why I came up with AppleScript/shell :-/

Comment: Ok, the following is pertinent information I need to know, if you want help with this. Do you process files in bulk, or one at a time? Do you process files from different users in the same run, or will they always be the same user? Are you running this from within the user's account, or from root, or an administrator's account?

Comment: Ok, I have added a German screenshot - maybe it helps. Files are processed in bulk and it is always one user doing it (no switching). The reason why I want to have the users is that the workflow shall be distributed to various Macs (not multiple users on one device). The script is run from a user's account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your original script, which seems to want to move all the files to the user's home folder, you can accomplish what you want using an automator variable. First, go to the upper left of the Automator window, click on the tab button that says 'Variables', then click on the 'Locations' item. Look for the item that says 'Home' (I believe that's 'Privat' on your machine's language):

[image]

This provides to a path to the user's home folder, for whichever user is running the workflow (system and machine independent). Drag this variable over to the `Copy Finder Items` (Finder-objekte kopieren) action, and drop it on the 'To:' ('Nach:') pull-down menu. It should look like this:

[image]

That should do the trick.

There are an assortment of system defined user paths you can choose from. You can also define a custom one using the special 'Text' variable (under 'Text & Data'), typing a path in standard unix notation where the tilde ('~') represents the user's home folder: e.g., `~/path/to/Custom Folder/`.

If you're doing something more complicated and *really* need to use a `Run AppleScript` action, all you need to know is that the list of files is passed into the action in the `input` variable as a list of aliases, and whatever you `return` (should be a list of aliases or posix paths), will be passed on to the next action. For example:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set output to {}
    repeat with this_item in input
        set new_item to this_item -- ... obviously you'd do something other than just copy
        copy new_item to end of output
    end repeat
    
    return output
end run
```

But it doesn't seem like you need to do that here; the special Automator variables should get you where you're going.

**EDIT**

Per comments, here's a revised version of the workflow...

Add the following actions to the workflow given in the question in place of the "Copy Finder Objects" action. Note that the second and sixth actions are set to ignore input from the previous action.  These actions do the following:

1. Save the list of files to be copied to a storage variable called 'FileToCopy'; pass no data on
2. Get the path to the user's home folder; pass it to the next action
3. Get the user's 'user name'; pass the home folder and user name to the next action as a list
4. Run an AppleScript that constructs a unix path string from the input list; pass the completed path string on to the next action
5. Save the path string into a variable called 'DestinationFolder'; pass no data on
6. Retrieves the list of files to copy we saved in step #1; pass it on to the next action
7. Copy the files to the selected folder, using the 'DestinationFolder' variable we saved in step #5; pass these on to the Rename Finder Items action (not shown here)

[image: revised workflow]

Give it a go, and let me know how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much! I checked out the variables but I think they don't work for me because I need a folder name depending on the user name. E.g. when Bos runs the script he copies to ~/BobsFolder/Outputs and when Pete runs it the script copies to ~/PetesFolder/AnotherFolder. I tried to run your AppleScript instead of the "Copy Finder Items" but nothing happens. Actually, I thought copying is just what I need since I am replacing the "Copy Finder Items" function.

Comment: The AppleScript I offered is an example that that explicitly doesn't do anything except copy the input to the output. You'd need to modify it to make it do something. But the 'variables' approach will still work. Give me a while and I'll post a revision.

Comment: It works, thank oyu very much!!! One additional question: When I ran the script several times for testing I noticed that the encrypted file in the destination folder has numbers as suffix, e.g. "filename (encrypted) 14.pdf". Are all the files buffered at some hidden place before copying them or how does the system know how many times I ran the script on a certain file already? I want to avoid piling up encrypted PDFs somewhere in my system ;)

Comment: @Cerd: When the system copies a file to a folder that already has a file of the same name, it adds an index: e.g., if you copy 'MyFile.doc' multiple times to the same folder, you'll get 'MyFile.doc', 'MyFile 2.doc', 'MyFile 3.doc', etc. Is that what you're seeing? if you click the 'Replacing existing files' checkbox in the 'Copy Finder Items' action, it will overwrite old copies rather than indexing new ones.

Comment: Yes, I would understand this behavior. But when I run the workflow on 'ABC.pdf' it creates 'ABC (encrypted).pdf' in the destination folder. I go ahead and delete 'ABC (encrypted).pdf' from destination folder and run the script again which results in 'ABC (encrypted) 2.pdf' even though nothing else is there anymore. This makes me wonder whether there is any sort of Temp-folder where encrypted files go first. To be honest I am a little confused why the workflow does not overwrite the original with an encyrpted file (which would be bad) because it's the first step before I even copy

Comment: @Cerd: Ah. Well, when I test the 'Encrypt PDF Documents', it does seem to create the encrypted file way down in temporary storage: `/private/var/folders/rl/zwlvv_hd6ss4c4yhb6nxxfz80000gn/T/...` Things in that folder are cleaned up periodically by the system (I don't know if it's daily or weekly), but it's certainly not going to happen immediately. However, now that we know it does this, you could replace the 'Copy Finder Items' action with the 'Move Finder Items'  action. Just grab the newly-created encrypted file and move it where you want it, no copying required.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Have a great weekend!