# Automator could not access required data

Tags: applescript, automator

I want to run an Automator workflow from within an AppleScript. When I use Terminal I can do:

```
/usr/bin/automator -i /Users/.../filename /Users/.../worfklowname.workflow/
```

But when I do this as part of the AppleScript via

```
do shell script "/usr/bin/automator -i /Users/.../filename /Users/.../worfklowname.workflow/"
```

I get an error stating that Automator could not access the required data. What's wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like it may be an issue with whatever workflow you are using - something simple like displaying the argument works for me.

Comment: I suspect that problem is the way you've tangled things up. You're using automator to run an AppleScript that runs a shell script that runs an automator workflow; you're handing things off so much it's no wonder you're getting a fumble. If you show more of the script your using (and give some idea what you'r trying to do) we may be able to untangle it.

Comment: The workflow I call is that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63129932/automator-copy-finder-object-with-applescript/63195333?noredirect=1#comment111920977_63195333 But the AppleScript I'm calling it from has several thousand lines of code

Comment: @Cerd: Oh, that's *my* post, right. The reason I wanted to know the surrounding AppleScript is that I thought things might work better if you simple used the `Run Workflow` action (instead of that chain of indirections). That would mean breaking out of the AppleScript to call a new action, and I don't know if that's feasible, because I don't know the structure.

Comment: Yes, that's your workflow :) But it is not possible to use the Run Workflow action because the position where I call it is nested into a set of if statements

Answer (score 0):

I [found](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=29258) a solution:

```
set startpath to "Macintosh HD:Users:...:filename"
set workflowpath to "Macintosh HD:Users:...:workflow"
set qtdstartpath to quoted form of (POSIX path of startpath)
set qtdworkflowpath to quoted form of (POSIX path of workflowpath)
set command to "/usr/bin/automator -i " & qtdstartpath & " " & qtdworkflowpath
do shell script command
```

It's probably due to all the entanglements that this solution also looks a bit non-straightforward :-D